# Multiple angular 2 apps and /api on same host with nginx

Tags: angular, nginx, config

I'm trying to achieve this goal with nginx configuration:

```
mydomain.com/api        should serve the php API
mydomain.com/login      should serve an angular 2 app
mydomain.com/dashboard  should serve another angular 2 app
```

The nginx.conf I post below works fine except for this (which is the problem i need help fixing):

When the user visits a route in angular like **mydomain.com/dashboard/forms** then the url is rewritten like this **mydomain.com/dashboard/dist/forms**

Here is the code tree:

```
├── mydomain.com
│   ├── app           // slim project
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── public
│   │   ├── dashboard // anuglar project
|   |   |   └── dist
│   │   └── login     // angular project
|   |       └── dist
```

And here is the server block I use:

```
server {

  listen 80;
  server_name mydomain.com;

  error_log /home/test/code/mydomain.com/error.log;
  access_log /home/test/code/mydomain.com/access.log;
  root /home/test/code/mydomain.com/public/;

  sendfile on;
  rewrite_log on;
  include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;

  gzip on;

  location ~ ^/(assets|bower_components|scripts|styles|views) {
    expires     31d;
    add_header  Cache-Control public;
  }

  ############################################################################
  #                             D A S H B O A R D
  ############################################################################

  location /dashboard/ {
    alias /home/test/code/mydomain.com/public/dashboard/dist/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }

  ############################################################################
  #                                L O G I N
  ############################################################################

  location /login/ {
    alias /home/test/code/mydomain.com/public/login/dist/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }

  ############################################################################
  #                                 A P I
  ############################################################################

  location ~ ^/api/(.*)$ {
    alias /home/test/code/mydomain.com/public;
    try_files $1 $1/ @php;
    index index.php;
  }

  location @php {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/api)(/.*)$;
    fastcgi_pass localhost:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/test/code/mydomain.com/public/index.php;
    fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 900;
  }
}
```

What should I change so that the "/dist" doesn't get written in the url?

Answer (score 2):

The configuration file is actually fine. The problem was building the angular app with --base-ref /dashboard/dist/ instead of plain /dashboard/