# Loading Angular apps through Nginx is very slow - Takes 60 seconds

Tags: angular, nginx, angular5, reverse-proxy

On the following repository:

https://github.com/napolev/lab-nginx-angular/tree/nasiruddin-suggestions

I have 3 elements

1. `nginx` server
2. vanilla Angular `app1`
3. vanilla Angular `app2`

`app2` is a clone of `app1`

I'm using `Windows 10` OS with `Cygwin`.

To try the system, open 3 terminal windows and do:

```
$ mkdir lab-nginx-angular
$ cd lab-nginx-angular
$ git clone https://github.com/napolev/lab-nginx-angular .
$ git checkout nasiruddin-suggestions
---
$ cd nginx
$ ./nginx.exe
---
$ cd app1
$ ng serve
---
$ cd app2
$ ng serve
```

inside file: `.angular-cli.json` I have the following (for instance: `app1`):

```
{
  ...
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {},
    "serve": {
      "host": "app1.example.com",
      "port": 4201
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Which causes `app1` be accessible on the browser through the url:

http://app1.example.com:4201

In the same way, `app2` is accessible on the browser through the url:

http://app2.example.com:4202

(please, modify the `hosts` file accordingly)

Then, with `Nginx` (reverse proxy) I can access both applications with urls:

http://app1.example.com

http://app2.example.com

using the same port, in this case: `80`.

Inside `Nginx`, for `app1`, I used the following configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name app1.example.com;
    location ~ ^/sockjs-node
    {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4201;
        include "../proxy_params.conf";
    }
    location /
    {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4201;
        include "../proxy_params.conf";
    }
}
```

My problem is that when loading both apps through `Nginx`, it takes exactly `60` seconds to load (don't know why, don't know how to solve it).

[image]

If I access both applications through:

http://app1.example.com:4201

http://app2.example.com:4202

they load quick, though.

Any idea on how to make both apps load with `Nginx` as quick as their original urls?

**EDIT 1**

Working on suggestions from **Nasiruddin** (other suggestions are welcome too).
Created a new branch for it, so please, do a `git` checkout:

```
$ git checkout nasiruddin-suggestions
```

https://github.com/napolev/lab-nginx-angular/tree/nasiruddin-suggestions

*Trying to find the piece of config that does the trick*

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using port you can go for multiple locations on same domain **if you want to load it on one domain**. You will not need to start **ng serve** every time.

The solution is to build the app using “base-href” option.

for example build multiple app with **base-href**:

```
cd app_one && ng build --base-href=/app_one/
cd app_two && ng build --base-href=/app_two/
cd app_three && ng build --base-href=/app_three/
```

This build option will lead to the situation where the index.html of your app will have a BASE href defined accordingly to the path defined in the command.

```
<base href=”/app_one/” />
```

For the NGINX setup, you’ll have to override the default NGINX settings by using the following configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name apps.example.com;
    location /app_one/ {
        alias /var/www/html/app_one/dist/;
        try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /app_one/index.html;
    }
    location /app_two/ {
        alias /var/www/html/app_two/dist/;
        try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /app_two/index.html;
    }
    location /app_three/ {
        alias /var/www/html/app_three/dist/;
        try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /app_three/index.html;
    }
}
```

This combination of ng build command and NGINX setup has the following advantages:

> - you can access your apps through the configured URLs
> - if you get on a Angular route, you can refresh pages without getting a 404

To Access app you can use url as

```
www.apps.example.com/app_one
www.apps.example.com/app_two
```

for more example please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43777791/multiple-angular-2-apps-and-api-on-same-host-with-nginx)

**Edit**

If you want to serve multiple you can use on multiple ports you can config NGINX as

this is my config for proxy passing to localport,

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name app1.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4200;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name app2.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

or for build app you can configure to,

```
server {
    listen 80 ;
    root /PATH/TO/APP_ONE/DIST/;
    index index.html index.htm;
    server_name app1.example.com;
    proxy_buffering on;
    proxy_buffer_size 1k;
    proxy_buffers 24 4k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 8k;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 2048m;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size 32k;
    location / {
          try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80 ;
    root /PATH/TO/APP_TWO/DIST/;
    index index.html index.htm;
    server_name app2.example.com;
    proxy_buffering on;
    proxy_buffer_size 1k;
    proxy_buffers 24 4k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 8k;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 2048m;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size 32k;
    location / {
          try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please, list how the configured urls look like? I mean, how the user access each app in the browser?, thanks

Comment: for example to access app_one, then url for it will be  www.apps.example.com/app_one

Comment: that doesn't work for me since I need to access each application like: http://app1.example.com and http://app2.example.com, without any path attached to the domain.

Comment: I prefer the idea I was working on at the beginning. Any idea about why is Nginx so slow with my configuration?

Comment: I created a new branch with your suggestions here: https://github.com/napolev/lab-nginx-angular/tree/nasiruddin-suggestions, but the apps continue taking 60 seconds to load through `Nginx`. I also edited my initial post to highlight I'm working based on your suggestions. Any other idea on this? Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176772/discussion-between-nasiruddin-saiyed-and-davidesp).